# Get data from FILE and export to DB LIVE

Tags: php, logging, cron, timeout

I am planing to make a script which load a log file and get info from it, and after that it just export it to databse, in general it looks easy but i have problem beause log file update every few seconds so how i keep my data updated in databse in same time as log file updates?

Main problems:

1. I have to reload log file always becuase it update as well
2. My script should not timeout or have keep restarting very often

I was thinking about using CRON but i am pretty sure my hosting provider will be not happy if i tell him i want some CRON sript run every few sec

Comment: Just a thought, would it not be easier to change whatever creates the log to write it to the database? Maybe if you specified which log file you were talking about.

Answer (score 0):

No possible to do it realtime because cronjobs have a minimum of 1 minute...

yes but you can tweak a deamon that sleeps for couble of seconds, but yes i dont know how big your log file is maybe with multiinsert it's possible to insert the complete data in seconds